# Limiting Request Body size to 5 GB in Apache httpd using LimitRequestBody directive

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

We are in the process of implementing certain controls in our installation of Apache httpd server.
One of the directives, we are trying to use is [LimitRequestBody](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

It states:

> This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning
>   unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body

We have a need to restrict upload size to 5 GB, however, directive allows max value of 2 GB or unlimited.  Using unlimited seems risky as one can upload few tera bytes of file and cause denial-of-service.

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Does unlimited really mean unlimited? Or is unlimited the same as 2147483647?